# Chirping in Kitchen - Always one minute apart

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, noise

So we've been getting this weird chirping noise in the kitchen. It's always just one chirp, and always a minute apart between chirps when I decided to time it. It first started yesterday in the morning, and then stopped later during the day, and today has started again, continuing on.
We don't have a smoke alarm in the kitchen, I've tried turning off the boiler and fridge, but the chirping carries on, and when I listen to where it's coming from, the sound seems to move.
Any help?

Comment: If you turn off all the circuit breakers does the chirping continue?

Comment: A bit more information: It always seems to start in the early morning, chirp for a few hours, then stop for the rest of the day. I just got back from work, and it started chirping at 6 in the morning.

Comment: Could it be a critter of some kind?  Do you have cicadas or crickets where you are?

Answer (score 3):

Even though you do not have a smoke alarm in the kitchen I would suggest that you check for low battery condition in all of your smoke alarms in the home. If you have not done so in more than a year the general advice is to replace all the smoke alarm batteries with fresh new ones.

I had the chirp problem at my house and can attest to the fact that it can be difficult to locate the source of the chirp. I believe that the problem is that the chirp sound is one that easily bounces and echos around the house. In addition I have found that the sound duration is so short that our brain has difficulty performing the triangulation that it normally uses to find the source of sounds.

Comment: One would also hope that a "friend" has not installed an annoy-a-tron device for the sole purpose of driving you crazy!

Comment: Replace batteries *annually*? That seems rather excessive unless you are using cheapie batteries. A duracell should be good for at least 3-5 and a an energizer "lithium" for 10.   I have one chirping, I haven't changed it because  a ceiling was later retrofit.  It's behind the ceiling, they buried it.  The ceiling went in 15 years ago.

Comment: @Harper - Newer smoke detectors are designed with built-in ("10 year" but YMMV) batteries. But in my area at least, the advice was "change your clocks, change your smoke detector batteries" - i.e., **twice** a year. Most don't bother until they hear the chirp, which is one reason for the new built-in long-life batteries (the other reasons get into profit margins...). The detectors from years ago were designed with older alkaline batteries in mind, not the newer lithium and others, so longer life now is reasonable with good batteries. But a couple $ on batteries is very cheap insurance.

Comment: don't smoke detectors chirp every 35 seconds instead of every min?

Comment: The 5 to 10 year "life" of batteries is for when they are sitting in a drawer NOT connected to anything. Smoke alarms are powering up a small heated chamber, constantly draining a small amount of power from the batteries at all times. Once a year is the MINIMUM change-out time, twice per year (i.e. with the time changes as suggested) is the safest bet.

Comment: +1 on the difficulty of locating the source. There is something about the frequencies they use on the smoke detector chirps. I have been fooled by the echos of those things, swearing the sounds were coming from rooms or areas where there were no detectors. My theory is that rooms with carpet and furniture absorb the sound more, kitchens are almost all hard surfaces that make the sound bounce around more.